# Automorphisms on Punctured Disc

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I have to find the automorphism group of the punctured unit disc $D = \{|z| <1\}\setminus \{0\}$.

I understand that if $f$ is an automorphism on $D$, then it will have either a (i) removable singularity or (ii) a pole of order 1 at $z=0$.

If it has a removable singularity at 0, then $f$ is a rotation. I am stuck at case (ii).

Also, using this result, later I also have to find the automorphism group of $\{|z|<1\}\setminus \{1/2\}$

Can anybody please help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bounded holomorphic function does not have a pole.

Comment: Right, thanks. So the automorphism group will consist of rotations only ?

Comment: Right. For the second part try conjugating by an automorphism of $D$ that sends $0$ to $\frac12$.

Comment: Yes, since these two sets are conformally equivalent, they will have the same automorphism group. Is that right ?

Comment: @CB_Student: Depends on what you mean by "same"; in one you get rotations, in the other rotations conjugated by an automorphism of the disk.  But yes, this conjugation gives an isomorphism between the automorphism groups.

Comment: Can you please help me with this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/303720/entire-function-which-equals-exponential-on-real-axis#comment657919_303720 ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant isomorphic, by 'same' :)